# Get value of a hidden field tag Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, hidden-field

I am lost, I do not know what I'm doing wrong! I have 4 radio buttons and a hidden field (value = "1"). When you click on the second radiobutton, the value of the hidden field changes to 2 and so on. This works fine with a js function.

Different divs will be showed when a different radiobutton is selected. Now, when I'm trying to get the value of the hidden field in my controller it always returns nil.

Here's the code:

### view:

(radiobuttons, hiddenfield and one div)

```
<div>
    <%= form_tag patients_path do %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'searchRBN', 'patient', true, :onchange => "checkRadioButton()" %>
        <%= label_tag :byPatient_patient, "Patient" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'searchRBN', 'staff', false, :onchange => "checkRadioButton()" %>
        <%= label_tag :byStaff_staff, "Staff" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'searchRBN', 'ocmw', false, :onchange => "checkRadioButton()" %>
        <%= label_tag :byOcmw_ocmw, "OCMW" %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'searchRBN', 'mutuality', false, :onchange => "checkRadioButton()" %>
        <%= label_tag :byMutuality_mutuality, "Mutuality" %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :hidden_one, "1" %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="searchByPatient">
    <%= form_tag patients_path, :method => 'get' do %>
        <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :search1, params[:search1] %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

### controller:

```
def index
    @staff_all = Staff.all
    @ocmw_all = Ocmw.all
    @mutuality_all = Mutuality.all
    debugger
    if params[:hidden_one] == '1'
      @patients = Patient.searchByName(params[:search1])
    elsif params[:hidden_one] == '2'
      @patients = Patient.searchByStaff(params[:search2])
    else
      @patients = Patient.all
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have two forms. When you submit the second form it won't send the fields of the first form. If you put everything in one form it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use only single form:
Also as a workaround use two submit tag in a single form:
differentiate both the action with `params[:action]`

For Example:

```
<%= form_for :attachment_metadata, :url=>{:action=>'delete_files'}, :html=>{:onsubmit=> "return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete selected files?');",:multipart => true} do |f| %>
   <table>
     ..........Some stuff here..........
   </table> 
<%= submit_tag 'Reprocess', :class =>'button' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Remove', :class =>'button' %>
<% end %>
```

`params[:commit]` can differentiate the actions of two submit tags.

```
@action = params[:commit]
```

it gives @action value as "Reprocess" if your click the Reprocess button and gives "Remove" value if you click the Remove button,

Then you will get your values.